# OpenTripPlanner 1.4 Elevation TIF Issues

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, wgs84, opentripplanner

I'm using the OpenTripPlanner routing engine (v1.4), and am trying to load in elevation information via a GeoTIFF file. When I load in my TIF file though, the elevations are always being set to 0.

The TIF file I'm using is from [Digital Elevation Model (DEM) of Australia](https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/89644), titled "Download 5m DEM GDA94 UTM zone 55 NSW QLD TAS VIC Quasigeoid (6.1GB)". When I debug the code, in `ElevationModule.getElevation` the line `coverage.evaluate(new DirectPosition2D(GeometryUtils.WGS84_XY, x, y), values);` always throws a `PointOutsideCoverageException`, causing the elevation at that point to be set to 0.

If however I try on a different GeoTIFF from the same site e.g. "Download 5m DEM GDA94 UTM zone 48 Christmas Island (17MB)" then it works fine, I get elevation as expected.

This is the first time I'm dipping my toes into the GIS world, so I'm not clear on all the nomenclature around formats etc. From what I have tried looking at using `gdalinfo`, the details of each TIFF are as follows:

**DEM GDA94 UTM zone 55 NSW QLD TAS VIC Quasigeoid (NOT WORKING)**

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: mdbaz55_qg.tif
Size is 118601, 182001
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["GDA_1994_MGA_Zone_55",
    GEOGCS["GDA94",
        DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010042,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6283"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",147],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","28355"]]
Origin = (210999.000000000000000,6901005.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (5.000000000000000,-5.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  210999.000, 6901005.000) (144d 3'42.56"E, 27d59' 5.19"S)
Lower Left  (  210999.000, 5991000.000) (143d47'11.44"E, 36d10'57.71"S)
Upper Right (  804004.000, 6901005.000) (150d 5'25.91"E, 27d58'53.16"S)
Lower Right (  804004.000, 5991000.000) (150d22'48.21"E, 36d10'41.18"S)
Center      (  507501.500, 6446002.500) (147d 4'46.29"E, 32d 7'20.37"S)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-3.40282299999999995e+38
  Metadata:
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
```

**DEM GDA94 UTM zone 48 Christmas Island (WORKING)**

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: christmasislandz48.tif
Size is 4200, 3600
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["GDA94 / MGA zone 48",
    BASEGEOGCRS["GDA94",
        DATUM["Geocentric Datum of Australia 1994",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6283]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Transverse Mercator",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",105,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (558000.000000000931323,8849000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (5.000000000000000,-5.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  558000.000, 8849000.000) (105d31'47.61"E, 10d24'42.75"S)
Lower Left  (  558000.000, 8831000.000) (105d31'48.61"E, 10d34'28.80"S)
Upper Right (  579000.000, 8849000.000) (105d43'18.27"E, 10d24'41.40"S)
Lower Right (  579000.000, 8831000.000) (105d43'19.63"E, 10d34'27.43"S)
Center      (  568500.000, 8840000.000) (105d37'33.53"E, 10d29'35.15"S)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-3.40282306073709653e+38
```

The code for OTP makes mention a lot of "WGS84_XY", and the fact that coordinates must be in long,lat format, not lat,long. Is there a GDAL command I can run to either:

1. Validate if coordinates are in long,lat format?
2. Validate if the TIFF supports this WGS84_XY?
3. Somehow convert a TIFF file to say "please convert my incompatible.tif to a new TIFF using the same format as my working.tif file"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familliar with your coordinate system, but for my region the solution was to convert local coordinate system to WGS 84 - EPSG code: 4326.

I did the conversion in [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/) using [Warp(reproject)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterprojections.html?highlight=warp#warp-reproject) tool which is derived from the GDAL warp utility. Choose int16 as output data type and .tif extension for reprojected output raster layer.